# ASP.NET - Get DropDownList SelectedValue for current Row when using RowCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, rowcommand

- When I run the row command event from a button on a gridview row I
  can detect the correct value from any field found on the eventrow.
- `hidID` which is a unique identifier reports correctly for each row as
  expected.
- `ddlVal` always reports the first item in the list and not the
  currently selected value.
- Can anyone offer explanation as to why a dropdownlist would not
  detect the currently selected value when using the command event?

---

**ASP.NET**

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="Server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="gv_RowCommand" EnableModelValidation="False">
    <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reason Missed" ItemStyle-CssClass="Inline" HeaderStyle-CssClass="NoSort" Visible="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqldatasource" DataValueField="ID" DataTextField="Text" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Select ..." Value="0"/>
          </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqldatasource" runat="Server" SelectCommand="sp" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"/>
```

---

**VB**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  Dim constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Con").ConnectionString
  sqldatasource.ConnectionString = constring

  Bind_gv()
End Sub

Protected Sub gv_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
  Dim rowIndex As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
  Dim row As GridViewRow = gv.Rows(rowIndex)
  Dim ddlVal As Integer = DirectCast(row.FindControl("ddl"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
  Dim hidID As Integer = DirectCast(row.FindControl("hidID"), HiddenField).Value
  'ETC ...
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the `DropDownList` values coming from the database? I am not sure but I guess, you missed something or there should not be any issue.

Comment: @AT-2016 yes they are bound from a sqldatasource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some further diagnosis I found that:

- The row command event first reloads the page.
- This triggers the pages life cycle.
- The `RowCommand` event is triggered after the `Page_Load` event.
- The `RowCommand` event is triggered before `PreRender` event.

The consequences of this are if you bind data in the `Page_Load` event then this data is bound/rebound before the `RowCommand` is trigger.

If, like I was in my case, you are binding your dropdownlist in the `Page_Load` event or binding the gridview and a sqldatasource in the `Page_Load` then any clientside changes will be lost prior to the `RowCommand` being triggered as they will reset to their initial values.

**ANSWER**

Bind your gridview in any event after the `RowCommand` fires such as `OnPreRenderComplete`. This way clientside changes will still be available up until the `RowCommand` event is triggered.